# Data-live-search feature for select tag is not working in react-bootstrap

Tags: reactjs, bootstrap-4, react-bootstrap

I'm trying to implement data-live-search in a react project and I'm using [react-bootstrap](https://react-bootstrap.github.io/components/forms/).
Code goes here:

```
        <Form.Control as="select" data-live-search="true" htmlSize="5" custom>
          {activities.map(i=>{return <option>{i}</option>})}
        </Form.Control>
```

Everything is working as expected but the search bar is not showing up.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After few searches, I got to know that data-live-search is not available in react-bootstrap.
But we can use [react-bootstrap-typeahead](https://github.com/ericgio/react-bootstrap-typeahead) instead, which works like charm for me.